# Error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to debug and fix this issue. I am using PrimeFaces in this and just updated it to version 10. Now we are facing errors on a specific page when I click on a hyperlink the below stack trace gets generated. I am not getting what it is saying. Any help regarding the issue I am facing and what should I try to fix it.

```
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{GroupHuntGroups.hyperlinkEdit_action}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
SEVERE: Thread:38 anypath.LoginFilter:doFilter()[Line 196] : LOGINFILTER - RETURN                                                                  -- Stack: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:internalDoFilter()[Line 241]; org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:doFilter()[Line 208]; org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve:invoke()[Line 218];
SEVERE: Thread:38 anypath.LoginFilter:doFilter()[Line 52] : LOGINFILTER                                                                            -- Stack: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:internalDoFilter()[Line 241]; org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:doFilter()[Line 208]; org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve:invoke()[Line 218];

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/anypath] threw exception [An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean GroupHuntGroupEdit] with root cause
Oops Exception: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean GroupHuntGroupEdit
Stack Trace:
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder:invokePostConstruct()[Line 227];
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder:build()[Line 103];
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager:createAndPush()[Line 409];
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager:create()[Line 269];
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver:resolveBean()[Line 257];
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver:getValue()[Line 117];
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver:_getValue()[Line 176];
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver:getValue()[Line 203];
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier:getValue()[Line 71];
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue:getValue()[Line 161];
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl:getValue()[Line 184];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression:getValue()[Line 109];
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl:createComponentApplyAnnotations()[Line 1943];
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl:createComponent()[Line 1149];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl:createComponent()[Line 596];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl:apply()[Line 175];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:apply()[Line 120];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler:apply()[Line 95];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:applyNextHandler()[Line 137];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl:apply()[Line 202];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:apply()[Line 120];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler:apply()[Line 95];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:applyNextHandler()[Line 137];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl:apply()[Line 202];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:apply()[Line 120];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler:apply()[Line 95];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:applyNextHandler()[Line 137];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl:apply()[Line 202];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:apply()[Line 120];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler:apply()[Line 95];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:applyNextHandler()[Line 137];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl:apply()[Line 202];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:apply()[Line 120];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler:apply()[Line 95];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:applyNextHandler()[Line 137];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl:apply()[Line 202];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler:apply()[Line 120];
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler:apply()[Line 95];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler:apply()[Line 93];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler:apply()[Line 87];
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet:apply()[Line 161];
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy:buildView()[Line 1004];
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase:execute()[Line 99];
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase:doPhase()[Line 101];
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl:render()[Line 219];
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet:service()[Line 659];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:internalDoFilter()[Line 303];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:doFilter()[Line 208];
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter:doFilter()[Line 81];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:internalDoFilter()[Line 241];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:doFilter()[Line 208];
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter:doFilter()[Line 52];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:internalDoFilter()[Line 241];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:doFilter()[Line 208];
    anypath.LoginFilter:doFilter()[Line 195];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:internalDoFilter()[Line 241];
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain:doFilter()[Line 208];
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve:invoke()[Line 218];
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve:invoke()[Line 110];
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase:invoke()[Line 498];
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve:invoke()[Line 169];
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve:invoke()[Line 103];
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve:invoke()[Line 962];
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve:invoke()[Line 116];
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter:service()[Line 445];
    org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor:process()[Line 190];
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler:process()[Line 637];
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor:run()[Line 316];
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker()[Line 1149];
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run()[Line 624];
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable:run()[Line 61];
    java.lang.Thread:run()[Line 748];
```

Comment: I don't think this is PrimeFaces related based on that stack trace?

Comment: @Melloware i think it is some kind of bean injection or ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException issue but i think ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is not of arrary it id just a warning.